How come these multiple asynchronous fs.createWriteStreams.write() tasks writing to the same file at the same time are not overlapping and jumbling?
I have written a simple node.js application and I have a question.
My program essentially iterates through a list of 1000 URLs, and for each URL it fetches some data, and for each response the program invokes a NEW writeable stream (fs.createWriteStream) and writes data to it.

Now here is my question/concern... Since many different invocations of this fs.createWriteStream().write() function will be called asynchronously under the hood (remember, 1000 URLs), therefore causing many OS level writes to invoke to the same file, how come no two writeStreams are writing their buffers to the same file at the exact same time and therefore jumbling and truncating into each other? It appears that each writeStream is appending its data to the file in a nice, pretty, orderly fashion (see below). I expected that while one write stream is writing to the file, another write stream's .write() event on the OS level would/could trigger and simultaneously write to the same file, jumbling the file contents.

Keep in mind, I don't care about the order of the data being written, but I do care that two writes do not occur on the file at the same time on the OS level, jumbling the file up.
**Here is the writeData function, for reference. Notice how, this writeData() function is being invoked 1000 every time and because ws is assigned in the function, a new write stream instance is being created each time:
const fs = require("fs");
const writeData = (csvString) => {
  const ws = fs.createWriteStream(output.txt), { flags: "a" });
  ws.write("\n" + csvString, () => {
     console.log("A buffer has been written to the file: ");
     console.log(csvString);
  });
}

module.exports = writeData;

Expectations vs. reality:
Here is what is actually being output...which appears GOOD, orderly, almost synchronous appearing.

"A buffer has been written to the file: "
<csvString prints here>
"A buffer has been written to the file: "
<csvString prints here>
"A buffer has been written to the file: "
<csvString prints here>
"A buffer has been written to the file: "
<csvString prints here>

Here is an example of what I expected to be output...which would be BAD, jumbled and multiple async write operations appending to the file at random based on however much time the OS decides to give the async .write() process/thread:
"A buffer has been written to the file: "
<csvString prints here>
 been written to the file: "
<next csvString prints here>
String prints here>
"A buffer has been wri
A buffer has been written to the file: "
<next csvStr
String prints here>
"A buffer has been written to the file: 
"r has been written to the file: "
<next csv

WriteFileSync()??
Maybe this whole original question is a design issue. It seems like a design flaw or anti pattern to asynchronously write multiple inputs of data (10, 100 or 1000) to the same file. I can understand one input to one file in a 1:1 manner running asynchronously, or even one input out to many files, but many inputs to one file seems to be a design flaw. In this case, maybe you'd want to use writeFileSync().
A SINGLE writeable stream as opposed to many.
For anyone reading this, a couple days have passed since my original question. I have realized that creating 1000 instances of a writeable stream to the same file is an anti pattern because essentially you're giving control of the order of the writing to the OS and anything can happen. What I've done in my program to fix this is to simply invoke ONE instance of a writable stream and have each http response data invoke .write() on this single stream. This way you can "control" the order of output to the file (as .write() from what I understand kind of queues output). I've realized there is no purpose in having multiple streams writing to the same file unless you need that stream to be custom in some way (high water mark customization, etc).

FWIW, one thing that's confusing about the way you phrased the question is that you're talking about expectations about the console.log output, which has nothing to do with the file streams. Multiple console.log calls never produce interleaved output, no matter how many async callbacks they originate from.

"asynchronous" doesn't mean "concurrent". Your 1000 callbacks will run one after the other. When a HTTP request completes, its callback will be queued to run at the next possible opportunity.
This applies to all callbacks in JavaScript; it's not specific to Node or to file operations.

Thank you for the answer however I think there is a slight misunderstanding I'd like to clear up, my bad. Yes, I understand the callbacks to the HTTP response will be queued to run synchronously on the single thread, however, the issue is that the fs.createWriteStream.write() async function is actually getting called 1000 times to write to the same file. So I'm not so concerned with my callbacks running concurrently, but the .write() operation under the hood. Would this not then mean that node.js is sending off 1000 "concurrent" writes to the OS which should jumble each other? Thanks.

Again, just because WriteStream.write() is an async function doesn't mean it does anything concurrently under the hood. I agree that it isn't obvious from the documentation, but your testing makes it pretty clear that Node internally takes care of locking. It probably doesn't have a choice, because operating systems don't permit the same file to be opened multiple times concurrently for writing, as that would always be a recipe for disaster. (I don't know where in Node this locking happens, but it's all open source and fairly readable so if you care enough you can dig in and find out.)

Thanks for the response. I will beg to differ. From the node.js documentation: "It is unsafe to use fs.writeFile() multiple times on the same file without waiting for the callback. For this scenario, fs.createWriteStream() is recommended". This insinuates that the node engine can attempt multiple underlying concurrent writeFile() processes/tasks to the same file which is not safe. Please inform me if I am incorrect in this I am totally willing to be wrong, however it seems that multiple writes can occur to the same file (race condition) concurrently. Thanks.

Sorry, I don't know these details. I agree with the edited question though: a single output stream seems like a better design, even if multiple streams appear to also work. "It is unsafe" doesn't mean "it's guaranteed to fail", just that Node doesn't promise that it won't fail in some way (such as throwing an exception, or producing unexpected results).

Node.js fs.createWriteStream() manages writes using an internal buffer and queue system. When you call write(), the data is added to the queue, and the stream ensures each write completes before starting the next. This sequential processing prevents concurrent writes from overlapping, so even if your async calls trigger multiple writes simultaneously, they’re executed in order.
https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/main/lib/internal/streams/writable.js

Thank you for the answer however I think there is a slight misunderstanding I'd like to clear up. The issue is that the fs.createWriteStream is getting invoked 1000 times in this example. So 1000 different streams. Then .write() is being called on each stream instantly and essentially concurrently. So I understand a single stream instance handling a queue, however this program has 1000 separate write streams being created, each writing some string. Hopefully that clears up my concern/question. Thanks.
